# React Native navigation.setParams not working within route.... 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.setParams')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a stacked navigator that when a user presses play from the 'Explore' page it navigates to the 'Theater' with the params passed in.(Works fine) From within the theater page the user has another list of videos (similar to Youtube's recommended list on mobile) where the user can click  another video to play from within the same component, and I am attempting to use the 'navigation.setParams', to update the components params, but it keeps returning undefined. Any  idea how to make this work? Any idea how youtube handles the recommended videos being clicked from the watch page on mobile?

Explorer Pressable:

```
              <Pressable
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate('Theater', {
                    videoid: uploads.videoid,
                    videotitle: uploads.videotitle,
                    videodescription: uploads.videodescription,
                    videofile: uploads.videofile,
                    videothumbnail: uploads.videothumbnail,
                    videocreator: uploads.channel_name,
                    creatoravatar: uploads.channelpic,
                    videoviewcount: uploads.videoviewcount,
                    videolikecount: uploads.videolikecount,
                    videodislikecount: uploads.videodislikecount,
                    channelid: uploads.channelid,
                  })
                }
                style={styles.buttonOpen}>
                <FontAwesome
                  name="play"
                  size={24}
                  color="#0c1559"
                  style={styles.play}
                />
              </Pressable>
```

Theater Pressable:

```
                <Pressable
                  onPress={
                    (() => console.log(uploads),
                    navigation.setParams({
                      videoid: uploads.videoid,
                      videotitle: uploads.videotitle,
                      videodescription: uploads.videodescription,
                      videofile: uploads.videofile,
                      videothumbnail: uploads.videothumbnail,
                      videocreator: uploads.channel_name,
                      creatoravatar: uploads.channelpic,
                      videoviewcount: uploads.videoviewcount,
                      videolikecount: uploads.videolikecount,
                      videodislikecount: uploads.videodislikecount,
                      channelid: uploads.channelid,
                    })
                    )
                  }
                  style={styles.buttonOpen}>
                  <FontAwesome
                    name="play"
                    size={24}
                    color="#0c1559"
                    style={styles.play}
                  />
                </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1):

For more clarity I was trying to use navigate.SetPramas from within a react-native-tabview rendered scene. To fix the issue I had to simply add 'const navigation = useNavigation();' directly into my functions used to render the tabs and it allowed me to setParams for the present screen.